# Django: how to access inline fields from parent model form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-validation

Here is a simple multiple choice application.

A Question can have 4 choices.

In the admin panel, when save new question, I want check number of choices that are empty(no words) but I don't know how to access the 4 choices.

How can I access choices' values inside QuestionForm's clean() function?

```
#model.py
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

#admin.py
class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 4
    can_delete = False
    max_num = 4 # fix to have 4 choices


class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        """
        HERE, i want to access the 4 choices model
        """
        return self.cleaned_data

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = QuestionForm  
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]           


admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
admin.site.register(Choice, ChoiceAdmin)
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to access from the inline side, rather than the main form.

Create a `ChoiceForm` inheriting from `ModelForm`, and replace the `clean()` method with yours, something like:

```
class ChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ChoiceForm, self).clean()
        for f in self.forms:
             f.cleaned_data['choice']  # contains the text you want
             # so you can check if it's empty and raise ValidationError()
             # if needed
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-clean-on-a-modelformset for details.